# Imread method in Xamarin Forms project can't find my image

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, emgucv

I'm trying to take the negative no an image on my app.
The image is in the folder drawable in the android project.

I've tried with just the name of the image, just like the image **xaml** :

```
<Image x:Name="img"
                Source="thanos.jpg" />
```

c#:

```
Mat image = CvInvoke.Imread("thanos.jpg", ImreadModes.AnyColor);
```

But I get the exception : `System.ArgumentException : File thanos.jpg do not exist`

I've tried with adding drawable, resources, /, \, in the path, but still the same error.

Any ideas ?

Comment: images stored in drawable are Resources, not files.  Imread() expects a file path.  Either you need to find an alternate method that will work with a resource or stream, or you need to copy the image from resources to a file

Comment: So my image in resources>drawable is no more a file ? How am I supposed to turn it into a file ?

Comment: read the bytes from resources and write it to the filesystem as a file

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll try this out.

Comment: Did you have update for this issue?

Comment: Yeah I'll had an anwser for this

Answer (score 0):

This solution is only working for android atm.

First, adding the android path `private const string pathAndroid = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.**YourAppName**/files"` because the          `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.**WhateverYouChooseThere**)` linked to other folders.

Then Imread does need a file, and therefore I added the file directly in the mobile phone (my app already contains the images), and combine the path with the file name :

```
var pathfile = Path.Combine(pathAndroid + "/hello.JPG"); //whatever your file name
```

Eventualy, I could work with Imread :

```
Mat img = CvInvoke.Imread(pathfile);
CvInvoke.CvtColor(img, img, ColorConversion.Rgb2Gray);
CvInvoke.Imwrite(pathAndroid + "/result.JPG", img); //save the image
```